# What's the easiest way to allow only vertical window resizing?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm coding an MFC application that needs to allow vertical window resizing and prevent horizontal resizing. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to catch `WM_SIZING` and `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to force the proper width, (`WM_NCHITTEST` to filter out any responses leading to the user trying to change the width (Might not be needed...)).

If there were no multi-monitor setups, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` alone would suffice.

Also take a look at `GetSystemMenu()`, for possibly tailoring your system menu.

BTW: This answer is not MFC-specific.

Comment: How exactly do I handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO for just one dimensional restriction?

Comment: Pass it on to the default window proc, and then correct the width before returning.

Comment: Is it necessary to handle both `WM_SIZING` *and* `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to prevent sizing in one direction or the other? If I'm remembering correctly, this can be elegantly done by handling only `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. (And why would you need `GetSystemMenu` in this case?)

Comment: @CodeGray: `For systems with multiple monitors, the ptMaxSize and ptMaxPosition members describe the maximized size and position of the window on the primary monitor, even if the window ultimately maximizes onto a secondary monitor. In that case, the window manager adjusts these values to compensate for differences between the primary monitor and the monitor that displays the window. Thus, if the user leaves ptMaxSize untouched, a window on a monitor larger than the primary monitor maximizes to the size of the larger monitor.` So, do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm sorry, I'm not following your drift. A code example would probably help. So far from what I've found, the easiest way to do what I want is to override `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and set `WINDOWPOS.cx` to the constant width of the window. One downside of this method though is that when a user tries to resize from the left side, the window looks like if it's being dragged to the left.

Comment: Well then it's not doing what you want, is it? At first I thought the same thing Cody Gray did, but I think Deduplicator has a good point with the multiple monitors thing. So start with WM_GETMINMAXINFO - that is where you put in the width restriction, it will let the window manager stop the resizing before it takes place instead of changing the window back from under the cursor. As for GetSystemMenu - I have two theories about what he meant; either to override or remove the Minimize/Maximize entries there, or he meant to say GetSystemMetrics().

Comment: OK. I got the trick with `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. The important thing when setting `MINMAXINFO.ptMaxTrackSize.x` to the size restriction is not to set it to 0, which may happen before the variable holding the constant width is initialized. Otherwise it will do what I need.

Comment: I see. The apps I had in mind where I'd done this actually disabled maximizing (it seems silly to "maximize" a window that is restricted to a particular width or height), so the issue you pulled out of the `MINMAXINFO` documentation didn't apply. In that case, you get everything you want by just handling `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. If you do need to support maximizing, though, you should be able to just leave `ptMaxSize` and `ptMaxPosition` untouched. That will give you the behavior that you would normally want, where a maximized window fills the entire monitor on which it is maximized. I've tested...

Comment: ...this out fairly extensively on setups with multiple monitors at various resolutions, and it is the behavior that I would expect. If you've restricted, say, the width to a fixed value, when maximized, the window will keep that width but adjust its height to fill the screen. There is no need to handle `WM_SIZING` as best I can tell, unless you want to restrict the range of the height as well. But in that case, you'd just turn off the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` style. (Sorry to return to this so late—it was on my "to do" list to investigate, and I finally got around to it.)